# Chrome crash after 1 hour of running due to out of memory. Javascript memory management issue probably

Tags: javascript, vue.js, out-of-memory, settimeout, long-polling

I'm doing a polling method to my API every 5 seconds, to get real-time data. The code below works but after 1 hour of running, the page crash(Aww Snap, with the dinosaur image and error: out of memory). The data I'm collecting is quite large, and I'm expecting that javascript will offload the memory(garbage collection) every time the function is being called again. I can see in the Chrome Task Manager, the memory footprint is growing over time. Is there a way to clear the memory or offload the memory from growing over time?

```
 data(){
        return{

            newdata:[],

        };

    },
methods: {
loadData:async function () {


              try {
                      let response = await axios.get('/monitoring_data');
                      if (response.status != 200) {
                        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
                        await this.loadData();
                      }else {

                        // Get the data
                        this.newdata= response.data.Ppahvc;

                        // Call loadData() again to get the next data
                         await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
                         await this.loadData();
      
                      }

                  } catch (e) {

                      await this.loadData();
                  }
                },
            },
mounted:function(){                     
                    this.loadData();
                  },
```

Comment: This is a fault of the app, not JS memory management. GC works as long as you allow it. That memory consumption grows with time means that's there's memory leak. Posted code isn't enough to suggest anything.

Comment: @EstusFlask I agree that there's a memory leak issue. But how do I offload a memory in a recursive function

Comment: It's not confirmed that it's recursive function that causes the problem. You can try to remove recursive call and use `async mounted(){ while (true) await this.loadData(); }` instead but I'm not sure there will be changes.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the loadData function recursivley (function calls itself) which is likely the cause of your memory issue because the browser has to remember these nested calls to eventually return again.

Try using an iterative approach instead:

```
setInterval(function {
  let response = await axios.get('/monitoring_data');
  this.newdata = response.data.Ppahvc;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: It is intended to be recursive and indefinite as I'm polling it every 5 seconds to get my data. IThank you for the suggestion

Comment: @zul If it is just about doing it endlessly a while(true) loop calling loadData would work.

Comment: would you mind giving me a reference or simple example? thank you in advance

Comment: @zul I edited the answer with an example using setInterval. In the background it does nothing else than an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setinterval` instead of calling the loadData function recursivley